# Return the id of the first element

Tags: xml, xslt

Here is my XML file :

```
<TestLog>
 <TestLogItem id="0">
  <Message>Message 1</Message>
 </TestLogItem>
 <TestLogItem id="1">
  <Message>Message 2</Message>
 </TestLogItem>
 <TestLogItem id="2">
  <Message>Message 3</Message>
 </TestLogItem>
 <TestLogItem id="3">
  <Message>End of TestCase1</Message>
 </TestLogItem>
 <TestLogItem id="4">
  <Message>Message p</Message>
 </TestLogItem>
 <TestLogItem id="5">
  <Message>Message m</Message>
 </TestLogItem>
 <TestLogItem id="6">
  <Message>Message s</Message>
 </TestLogItem>
 <TestLogItem id="7">
  <Message>Message u</Message>
 </TestLogItem>
 <TestLogItem id="8">
  <Message>Message a</Message>
 </TestLogItem>
 <TestLogItem id="9">
  <Message>End of TestCase 2</Message>
 </TestLogItem>
</TestLog>
```

I use a key which takes all the TestLogItem above the TestLogItem that contains 'End of TestCase'. Now I would like to return the @id which follows the end of TestCase (for example : return '4' after the End of TestCase1).
I don't have any idea to do it.
This is my current XSLT :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="k" match="TestLogItem[string(Message)]" use="following-sibling::TestLogItem[contains(Message, 'TestCase')][1]/@id"/><!-- key which locates the end of each TestCase -->
    <xsl:template match="/TestLog">
        <html>

                    <xsl:for-each select="TestLogItem[contains(Message, 'TestCase')]"><!-- for-each loop which condition is the equivalent of testing each TestCase -->                     
                        <xsl:variable name="number_TC" select="substring(Message, 19, 7)"/>                                         
                        <tr><!-- for each line -->
                            <xsl:choose><!-- The test -->
                                <xsl:when test="key('k',@id)[contains(TypeDescription, 'Error')]">
                                    <td bgcolor="#FF0000">
                                        Test <xsl:value-of select="$number_TC"/><!-- display of the variable which is the number of the TestCase -->
                                    </td>
                                    <td bgcolor="#FF0000"> NOK </td>
                                    <td bgcolor="#FFFF00">
                                        <xsl:for-each select="key('k',@id)[contains(TypeDescription, 'Error')]">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="Message"/>
                                            <xsl:text> // </xsl:text>                                   
                                        </xsl:for-each>
                                    </td>
                                    <td bgcolor="#FF0000"> <xsl:value-of select="Time"/></td> 
                                </xsl:when>

                            </xsl:choose>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>

        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Isn't that the first *following-sibling*?

Comment: I am using this key :
<xsl:key use="following-sibling::TestLogItem[contains(Message, 'TestCase')][1]/@id" match="TestLogItem[string(Message)]" name="k"/>

Comment: Please show your current XSLT stylesheet (a [minimal, complete and verifiable version of it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that is) instead of posting an isolated snippet as a comment. Also, show what the output should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're not using `key`s just right here...  And it doesn't seem like you really need one either.

Here's a somewhat simplified version of your XSLT that seems to do what you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/TestLog">
        <html>

            <xsl:for-each select="TestLogItem/Message[contains(text(),'End of TestCase') and boolean(../following-sibling::TestLogItem/@id)]">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />'s following-sibling has ID: <xsl:value-of select="../following-sibling::TestLogItem/@id" />
            </xsl:for-each>

        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The idea is to select `TestLogItem`s that have a message containing 'End of TestCase' **and** have a `following::sibling` TestLogItem with an ID.  Output:

```
<html>End of TestCase1's following-sibling has ID: 4</html>
```

If you were to remove the second condition on the `for-each` (`and boolean(../following-sibling::TestLogItem/@id)`), you'd get this output (slightly reformatted for readability):

```
<html>End of TestCase1's following-sibling has ID: 4 
End of TestCase 2's following-sibling has ID: </html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer !
What if I want to display the "Message m" (in TestLogItem id="5") and displaying its position (i.e. position 2 because it is the second message in the TestCase 2) ?

Comment: I'm not really clear where or how you want to display that.  What's the rule?  Always display the second one after you find the end of a test case?  In that case, just use the `following-sibling` logic twice, i.e. `<xsl:value-of select="../following-sibling::TestLogItem/following-sibling::TestLogItem">`, and it'd always be the second one.  Otherwise, sounds like you have a different question than originally posted...

Comment: Well you're right, it is not the original question. Nevermind, thank  you for your quick and clear answer :)